# Getting (403) Forbidden.Error for another ClientContext

Tags: development, client-object-model

```
          using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://site-admin.sharepoint.com/"))
        {
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "******".ToCharArray())
                password.AppendChar(c);
            tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@Sharepoint.com", password);
            var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);
            string mainpath = "https://litwareinc20.sharepoint.com/";
            SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable sitePropEnumerable = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);
            tenantContext.Load(sitePropEnumerable);

            tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();

            string siteUrl = "";

            foreach (SiteProperties property in sitePropEnumerable)
            {
                Response.Write(property.Title + " : " + property.Url + " <br/>");
                siteUrl = property.Url;

                ClientContext clientContext1 = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
                Web web = cc.Web;

                clientContext1.Load(web);

                Response.Write("Web Title : " + web.Title);

                clientContext1.Load(clientContext1.Web);
                clientContext1.Load(clientContext1.Web.Webs);
               clientContext1.ExecuteQuery();
                string allsitecollections = "";

                 for (int i = 0; i < clientContext1.Web.Webs.Count; i++)
                   {

                     allsitecollections = tenantContext.Web.Webs[i].Url + "\n";
                     Response.Write("<br/> All Sites under : " + property.Title + "Site Collection is :" + allsitecollections + "<br/>");

                    }


                  }

        }
```

I want to retrieve all the sites from all site collections. But as I create another client context, I get the error

`Error : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden at clientContext1.ExecuteQuery();`

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the SharePointOnlineCredentials for clientContext1. Please specify the login credentials same way as you did for the tenantContext.

Comment: As you suggest, I have included this line :                 SecureString password = new SecureString();
      foreach (char c in "******".ToCharArray())
               password.AppendChar(c);
            clientContext1.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("adam@litwareinc20.onmicrosoft.com", password);                                          But I get The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: http://litwareinc20-public.sharepoint.com for this site collection only the problem exist. Otherwise it go forward for other site collection.

Comment: Check that sitecollection works through browser . Also check the permission of the user credential passed in code in that particular site

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me. For now I have skipped that particular sitecollection.